# Comparing topologies on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$: product, dictionary and subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $I=[0,1]$. Compare the product topology on $I\times I$ , the dictionary order topology on $I\times I$ , and the topology $I\times I$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order topology.

First of all, I know that the product topology on $X\times Y$, being $X$ and $Y$ topologies, is generated by the collection of sets of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$. Therefore, $I\times I$ will be generated by such collection. But what are opens in $I$? I must assume some kind of standard topology? Should it be the one generated by opens in the form $(a,b)$? I think no, because there's no basis element of this form that contains $0,\frac{1}{2}$ for example.

Now, for the dictionary order topology, I must assume basis elements of the form:

$$(a,b), [a_0,b), (a,b_0]$$

where $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 1$

right?

And what about the third topology?

I know that comparing them means finding if some topology is contained in another, but how to compare such strange topologies?

Comment: The topology on $I$ is the one that it inherits from the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. One base for it consists of all intervals $(a,b)$ with $0\le a<b\le 1$, all intervals $[0,a)$ with $0<a\le 1$, and all intervals $(a,1]$ with $0\le a<1$. However, you can simplify matters: the product topology that this yields on $I\times I$ is the same as the topology that $I\times I$ inherits from $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ with its product topology, so the product topology on $I\times I$ is just its usual relative topology as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: The dictionary order topology on $I\times I$ is generated by the set of all intervals of the forms $(a,b),[a_0,b)$, and $(a,b_0]$ **where these intervals are taken in** $I\times I$, **not in** $I$. In other words, $a_0,a,b$, and $b_0$ are points in $I\times I$, not in $I$. Specifically, $a_0=\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $b_0=\langle 1,1\rangle$. An open interval $(a,b)$, where $a=\langle x_a,y_a\rangle$ and $b=\langle x_b,y_b\rangle$, consists of all points of $I\times I$ that are strictly between $a$ and $b$ in the dictionary order. If $x_a<x_b$, these are the points $\langle x,y\rangle$ ...

Comment: ... such that $x_a<x<x_b$, or $x=x_a$ and $y_a<y\le 1$, or $x=x_b$ and $0\le y<y_b$. If $x_a=x_b$, they are the point $\langle x_a,y\rangle$ such that $y_a<y<y_b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The basis elements of each topology are:

1. The subspace topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$:
   $$
   ((x_1, x_2) \cap [0, 1]) \times ((y_1, y_2) \cap [0, 1])
   $$
2. The dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ has three types of basis elements:
   $$
   (x_1 \times y_1, x_2 \times y_2), [0 \times 0, x_2 \times y_2), (x_1 \times y_1, 1 \times 1]
   $$
3. The subspace topology inherited from the product topology on $\mathbb R_d \times \mathbb R$, where $\mathbb R_d$ is the reals with the discrete topology:
   $$
   \{x\} \times ((y_1, y_2) \cap [0, 1])
   $$

Comment: But there was nothing saying that the first topology is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$